# Create a file containing a matrix of integers.replace the row elements with the first negative element with the column elements with the same number

Tags: arrays, c, file, matrix

**TASK:**
Create a file containing a matrix of integers `A` of dimension `m*m`. Without reading the matrix into memory, replace the row elements with the first negative element with the column elements with the same number.
Print the original matrix and the resulting matrix line by line. It outputs the same matrix to me. And I need to replace the row elements with the column elements.

I have no problems with the matrix creation functions. But the problem is with the `read_k` function .

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// creating a binary file with the name,
// containing N*N integers.
void create_file(char *name, int n)
{
    FILE *f = fopen(name,"wb");
    if (f==NULL) 
    {
        printf("file creation error \n");
        system("pause");
        return ;
    }
    // write the variable n to the file
    fwrite(&n,sizeof(n),1,f);
    int i;
    // write the elements of the square matrix to the file.
    for( i=0;i<n*n;i++)
    {
        int z = rand()%200-rand()%100;
        fwrite(&z,sizeof(int),1,f);
    }
    fclose(f);
}

// function for reading a file with the name.
void read_file(char *name)
{
    int m;
    FILE *f = fopen(name,"rb");
    if (f==NULL) 
    {
        printf("file not found \n");
        system("pause");
        return ;
    }
    
    int i = 0;
    // reading the dimension of the matrix..
    int z;
    fread(&m,sizeof(int),1,f);
    //reading the entire matrix and displaying it on the screen..
    while(!feof(f))
    {
        if (i>=m&&i%m==0)
            printf("\n");
        if(fread(&z,sizeof(int),1,f)!=1) 
            break;
        printf("%8d",z);
        i++;
    }
    fclose(f);
}

void read_k(char *name, int n)
{
    char *A[30];
    int m;
    FILE *f = fopen(name,"rb");
    if (f==NULL) 
    {
        printf("file not found \n");
        system("pause");
        return ;
    }
    
    int z;
    int i,j;
    
    fread(&m,sizeof(int),1,f);
    
    for( i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        if(i<0)
        { 
            A[i][j]=A[j][i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    
    while(!feof(f))
    {
        if (i>=m&&i%m==0)
            printf("\n");
        if(fread(&z,sizeof(int),1,f)!=1) break;
            printf("%8d",z);
        i++;
    }
    fclose(f);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char Fname[30];
    int n,m;
    printf("file name: ");
    scanf("%s",Fname);
    printf("enter the number of rows in the matrix: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    
    create_file(Fname,n);
    printf("matrix : \n");
    read_file(Fname);
    printf("the new matrix %d \n",m);
    read_k(Fname,n);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What problem? Ask a specific question. What does the `read_k` function do that you do not want it to do?

Comment: the function should change the row elements(the row whose first element is negative) to the column elements with the same number.and output a new matrix

Comment: sample/examples input and outputs are better than description

Comment: input
2 3 5 
-3 5 4
1 2 3 
output
2 3 5
3 5 2
1 2 3

Comment: how do I write a function such that the matrix has changed in this way?